# How to concatenate hex byte array to long int without using union in C?

Tags: c

I have an array. Array bytes are in hexadecimal. Now I am trying to concatenate array index 1 to 4 in to unsigned long int and 5 to 8 in to one more unsigned long int and index 9 and 10 to unsigned int. I tried like this. But it's not working. I do not want to use union to concatenate. I am using this code in STM32F4-Discovery.

This is a receive interrupt Handler function :

```
  void usart1_IRqHandler()
  {
  unsigned char received_string[20];
  unsigned long int Addr1=0,Addr2=0;
  unsigned int Addr=0;
  
  /*Code to Receive Entire packet.......
   .....................................
   .....................................
  At this point whole packet is received, now I want to send back the response to the target node using address from received data, So first step is to concatenate address bytes*/ 
  
  /*From the logic analyzer I can observe the received_string bytes as shown below 
  received_string[1]=0x00; 
  received_string[2]=0x13;
  received_string[3]=0xA2;
  received_string[4]=0x00;

  received_string[5]=0x40;
  received_string[6]=0xB4;
  received_string[7]=0x14;
  received_string[8]=0x35;

  received_string[9]=0x8E;
  received_string[10]=0xC7;*/

  Addr1 =  (received_string[1]<<24)| (received_string[2]<<16)| (received_string[3]  <<8)| received_string[4]);
  Addr2 =  (received_string[5]<<24)| (received_string[6]<<16)|(received_string[7]  <<8)| received_string[8]);           
  Addr =  (received_string[9]<<8)| (received_string[10]);   

  Send_packet(Addr1,Addr2,Addr);
  }
```

Function Send Packet will target remote node with these address.

```
     Send_packet(unsigned long int Addr1,unsigned long int Addr1,unsigned int Addr)
    {
      unsigned char tx_buf[20];
      tx_buf[5]=(Addr1>>24) & 0xff;
      tx_buf[6]=(Addr1>>16) & 0xff;
      tx_buf[7]=(Addr1>>8)  & 0xff;
      tx_buf[8]=(Addr1>>0)  & 0xff;

      tx_buf[9]=(Addr2>>24)  & 0xff;
      tx_buf[10]=(Addr2>>16) & 0xff;
      tx_buf[11]=(Addr3>>8)  & 0xff;
      tx_buf[12]=(Addr4>>0)  & 0xff;

      tx_buf[9]=(Addr2>>8)  & 0xff;
      tx_buf[10]=(Addr2>>0) & 0xff;
     
      usart_send(tx_buf);
      
   }
```

This is the output of sending packet in logic analyzer.

```
  Addr1=0xA2401437
  Addr2=0x025500A2
  Addr=0x4014
```

Since the address does not matched, I am not able to target the remote node.

Comment: I suppose that in your actual code the variable names actually match?

Comment: did you intentionally leave out `received_string[0]`?

Comment: Yes variable names are matching. Actually received string[0] is a start delimiter, which I don't need, from received_string[1] to received_string[4], 5 to 8 and 9 to 10 are remote nodes Address. So i am concern only about the address.

Comment: When and where do you look at the contents of the variables? How do you do it? (And please edit the question to reflect the actual code, especially regarding the variable names.)

Comment: ' Array bytes are in hexadecimal': no they aren't. They are in binary. There is no such thing as a hexadecimal byte. Hex is a notation, not a representation.

Answer (score 1):

The question is missing a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and lacks details on how the information was acquired. However, the basic idea of how to convert the number is correct (the code in the question does not compile, so there's no way to tell what code was actually tested by the OP).

Below is an example that demonstrates it's working:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char received_string[20];
    
    received_string[1] = 0x00;
    received_string[2] = 0x13;
    received_string[3] = 0xA2;
    received_string[4] = 0x00;
    
    received_string[5] = 0x40;
    received_string[6] = 0xB4;
    received_string[7] = 0x14;
    received_string[8] = 0x35;

    received_string[9] = 0x8E;
    received_string[10] = 0xC7;
    
    unsigned long int Addr1 = (received_string[1] << 24) | (received_string[2] << 16) | 
                              (received_string[3] << 8) | received_string[4];
    unsigned long int Addr2 = (received_string[5] << 24) | (received_string[6] << 16) | 
                              (received_string[7] << 8) | received_string[8];
    unsigned int Addr = (received_string[9] << 8) | (received_string[10]);
    
    printf("Addr1 = %08lX\n", Addr1);
    printf("Addr2 = %08lX\n", Addr2);
    printf("Addr = %04X\n", Addr);

    return 0;
}
```

This will print:

```
Addr1 = 0013A200
Addr2 = 40B41435
Addr = 8EC7
```

NB: As correctly stated by user M.M. in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366355/how-to-concatenate-hex-byte-array-to-long-int-without-using-union-in-c#comment46919546_29366605) on the [answer of Yasir Majeed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29366605/10669875), the masking is entirely unnecessary. It will either be optimized away by the compiler or insert useless instructions.

Note, however, that to make this code more portable, the bytes should be cast to `unsigned long` before shifting. Otherwise, this will fail on platforms where `sizeof(int) < 4`.

Comment: Even better, cast to `uint32_t` to avoid any doubt and increase portability.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Why is that more portable? `unsigned long` is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits and works on all compilers.

Comment: Sure, if you don't mind it being larger than necessary on some platforms. But if you explicitly want to read a 32-bit address, I still think that `uint32_t` is the best choice.

Comment: @G.Sliepen, I think I can live with loosing 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform (ignoring the fact that `uint32_t` variables will probably be 64-bit aligned anyway and that the additional type conversions might increase code size by more than 8 bytes). However, the OP explicitly asked for and already used (`unsigned`) `long` in the code and I think this discussion is quite irrelevant and out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = ((received_string[0] << 24) & 0xff000000) |
                ((received_string[1] << 16) & 0x00ff0000) |
                ((received_string[2] << 8) & 0x0000ff00) |
                ((received_string[3] << 0) & 0x000000ff);
```

This will construct the unsigned int for you. You can change the indexes of my example to your desired indexes

Comment: Your masks are redundant, this has just the same effect as the original code (except that you also changed the array indices)

Comment: How can you say this. This is just & operation. Not assignment. 0xff will & only with the lower byte. What about the higher bytes?? I have implemented it and using in several applications.

Comment: Here is an example. Declare a char array[4] = {'1','2','3','4'}; which is basically 0x31,0x32,0x33,0x34. When you run the above code the value of 'i' will be 0x31323334. And I got a downvote for correct solution